# exclude scheduled post from the Query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want exclude the scheduled posts from my custom theme.
I used the action hook

> pre_get_posts

in my functions file to retrieve just the published posts, but the scheduled post still appear:

```
function exclude_scheduled_posts( $query ){

if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ){
    $query->set('post_status' ,  array('publish'));
}
return ;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_scheduled_posts');
```

How can I filter the scheduled posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can filter scheduled posts using post_status argument in your code.. you can follow this for you function code..

```
* 'publish' - a published post or page
* 'pending' - post is pending review
* 'draft' - a post in draft status
* 'auto-draft' - a newly created post, with no content
* 'future' - a post to publish in the future
* 'private' - not visible to users who are not logged in
* 'inherit' - a revision. see get_children.
* 'trash' - post is in trash.

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
    'post_status'            => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash'),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: but this code will display the scheduled posts. i want the  i want the opposite

Comment: hey @YounesDro, i have updated my answer and also showed all the post status that you can use within query arguments.